# Inconsistent edge slide direction

Tags: edges, topology

I'm discovering sewing pattern making techniques in Blender 3.5. I try to add seam allowance to my pattern using the edge slide operator but one of the pieces changes in the opposite direction than the others.

[image: mesh after edge slide]

I made this mesh from a pipe shaped mesh surface. I splitted the mesh with edge split modifier then I used geometry nodes to UV unwrap the mesh and to modify vertex positions according to the to UV coordinates.

[image]

Before edge sliding I had to apply both modifiers because I don't know any procedural method for edge sliding. Here is the resulting mesh.

[image]

How can I fix this issue? I tried to alter my modifier pipeline and to recalculate normals before edge sliding, but nothing helped.